# Approval History Related List for a Custom Object

Tags: customization

I have a custom object with an approval process, how can I get the approval related list on the page of that custom object.

Comment: You can ask these types of question in Salesforce official discussion forum.

Comment: @JitendraZaa This kind question is perfectly acceptable to be asked here, The Salesforce Stackexchange isn't only for Apex related queries

Comment: I agree.. this question is acceptable.. These type of questions were really the reason for us to start a stackexchange site as these would flagged off in SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you will navigate to "Edit Pagelayout" in "Related List" there is option to import "Approval History".

For adding the "Approval History" related list in VF page, you can try this :

```
<apex:relatedList list="ProcessSteps" ></apex:relatedList>
```

Please go through this URL : 
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/How-to-Display-quot-Approval-History-quot-as-the-only-Related/td-p/103438

Comment: That is correct !! But what if i have a visualforce page, standard controller, custom controller

Comment: <apex:RelatedList> tag is not working for me

Comment: Roshan, Please find updated Answer

Comment: @JitendraZaa Will this remove the unwanted text (pending for first approval which makes sense for only parallel approver) from the approval history as well ?